# How to use Spring Data Elasticsearch @Query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

When I use the following code as Spring docs said eclipse always show Syntax error on token.

```
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
@Query("{"bool" : {"must" : {"field" : {"name" : "?0"}}}}")
Page<Book> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable);}
```

Comment: Which token exactly is Eclipse complaining about?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it doesn't like the query inside the `@Query` annotation. 
You need to escape the double quotes in your query.

```
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
@Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"field\" : {\"name\" : \"?0\"}}}}")
Page<Book> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable);}
```

That's a documentation bug, indeed. In [their tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/416daef2f92734d0d1b5681265d719b9f1c347d5/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories/custom/SampleCustomMethodRepository.java), however, we can find out that the doubles quotes must be escaped, since the double quote is a reserved delimiter character in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your JSON query (under "query": {, without the query tag).

Write @Query("") in your code and paste your copied query inside the quotes, your IDE will probably automatically escape the query.

Useful for long queries.